# Fractal Prince/Quantum Thief - Gevulot

Tags: fractal-prince, quantum-thief

Why was Gevulot put in place? For that matter, why was it only in place on Mars, and not in other parts of that universe described by the author?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it developed from surveillance and control systems designed at the Oubliette's origins as a penal colony. This is one of the big reveals in the first book.